# MongoDB permissions: restrict access to two databases

Tags: mongodb, permissions, roles

I am trying to implement some restrictions on my MongoDB server:

Two databases on my server should be restricted regarding delete/drop operations - only a special user account should be allowed to do so. All the other database should be totally unrestricted (of course excluding the admin database):

I tried to model this situation using two users:

```
       |   database A & B   |  all the other databases |
---------------------------------------------------------
user a |    read & write    |       read & write       |
user b |      read-only     |       read & write       |
```

Making everybody read all databases is easy using the `readAnyDatabase`role.
However modelling that user b can only read database A & B but has read & write access to all the other databases (including those databases that are created later on) gives me a headache.

How can this security model be implemented in MongoDB?

Comment: So in short you want `User B` to have limited functioning that is read only on Specific DB ?

Comment: Yes. But at the same time this user should be have full permissions on all other databases that currently exist and will exist in future (including those created by user b).

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible.

You can combine multiple roles and inherit them from multiple databases, but:

> When granted a role, a user receives all the privileges of that role.
>   A user can have several roles concurrently, in which case the user
>   receives the **union** of all the privileges of the respective roles.

-

> Roles always grant privileges and never limit access. For example, if
>   a user has both **read** and **readWriteAnyDatabase** roles on a database, the **greater access prevails.**

You can find these paragraphs in [mongodb authorization doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/).

In order to give read write on all future databases, you need to set `readWriteAnyDatabase` role to userb. That means, you can't downgrade to `read` role, for the A and B databases.

I am afraid you need to set the roles manually for the new dbs.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

instead of `auth = true`, as for the rest Rohit answer did the job.

See also : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325891/1814774

Comment: `auth=true` is an older/legacy formatting of mongodb.conf and `security: authorization: enabled` is a newer in yaml. Either format can be used and older is still utilized, for example, I have older in mongodb 3.6.8 from apt in Ubuntu 20.04.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517872/the-mongodb-docs-say-my-config-file-should-be-yaml-its-not-why

Answer (score 1):

First of all enable authentication in your `mongodb.conf` file

```
auth = true
```

Create a database `perm` for holding user permissions that we are going to create below.

```
use perm
```

then create `userb` with read-only permissions for `DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB`

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "userb",
      pwd: "12345",
      roles: [
         { role: "read", db: "DatabaseA" },
         { role: "read", db: "DatabaseB" }
      ]
    }
)
```

`userb` will only be allowed to read `DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB` rest all databases access to userb will be `read-write`

Now `userb` can login with below command

```
mongo --port 27017 -u userb -p 12345 --authenticationDatabase perm
```

Comment: userb has read-access to DatabaseA and DatabaseB, but what about the other databases? In my question I wrote that I need userb to be able to access the other databases read & write. Using the userb as created by the shown command this does not work as userb does not have access to any other database.