# Can't connect to MongoDB with authentication enabled

Tags: mongodb, authentication, database

I'm running the latest MongoDB for Ubuntu 14.04

- I have created a user named "admin" with "userAdminAnyDatabase" role
- I can access databases locally and externally
- I can login with "admin' with SHA-SCRAM-1

When I edit to config file to restrict access only with authentication things go wrong. What happens:

1. I uncomment "#auth = true" in the config file.
2. I cannot access with the correct credentials of the "admin" account.

Bear in mind that I do use "service mongod restart" after making changes.

Config file for reference:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


#processManagement:

#security:
#auth = true
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:
#snmp:
```

Snapshot of database for reference:

[image: Database]

What's going wrong?

Comment: Which version of the manager are you using? Can you access mongo from the cli?

Comment: Using version 3.1.0.5 and yes I can, until I enable authorisation.

Comment: Are you sure that manager supports SHA-SCRAM-1?

Comment: @DannyVarod It's an option in a ListView when creating a new connection so it should :)

Comment: what command you are using for that may i know ? I have done the same thing in ubuntu 15.x version

Comment: you are using nosql manager tool but once check it using command prompt also , open command prompt and go to mongodb installation directory go to "bin" directory in that and please type "mongo yourDatabaseName -u dbusername -p dbpassword"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that `auth = true` is an invalid configuration and your mongod is not starting because of it. To enable [authorization](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization), try using the following instead:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Then, to connect to the database, make sure that your client is using the correct [authentication database and authentication mechanism](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-shell-authentication-options).  This can be done using the commmand line by the following command:

```
mongo localhost -u admin -p myAdminPass --authenticationDatabase admin --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Comment: I must've used an old version setting? I tried with the correct config and it actually makes no difference. Thanks though.

Comment: @ManyQuestions I updated my answer to include the `--authenticationDatabase` command-line switch.  I am also not able to authenticate in my local MongoDB unless I specify it.  I don't know how to specify it in your graphical client.  Can you try it out please?

Comment: There's a field in which you can give in the auth database

Comment: I just noticed this coming up though: 2015-10-25 T12:23:12.256-0400 I ACCESS   [conn1] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client xx.XX.xx.xx ; UserNotFound Could not find user admin@admin

Comment: @ManyQuestions Maybe you created the user the old 2.X way?  Try dropping and recreating the user with [db.createUser](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/) because you can [get that error if you created it with db.addUser](http://serverfault.com/a/694202/318588).

Comment: I actually created one wit the old command first but noticed my mistake after; so I corrected it with the GUI tool. Maybe it uses the old command to create users, that would be a probably cause.

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you follow the instructions in [Enable Client Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) to create the user and enable authentication?
2. What is the output of your log, when you try to access mongoDB with credentials?
3. Did you tell mongoDB somewhere to use the config file? Try to start mongoDB locally on the PC mongoDB is running with `mongod --config ../etc/mongod.conf` and then try to connect from your Windows PC like you did before.