# Cannot connect with authentication to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

There's another answer here: [Can't connect to MongoDB with authentication enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287559/cant-connect-to-mongodb-with-authentication-enabled). I tried that but still can;t figure out what's wrong why my configuration.

I use Ubuntu 14.04, Mongo 3.4.1(latest) installed as a service

First after installation I run this command, just like its documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/):

```
mongo --port 27017
use admin
db.createUser({user: "adminUser",pwd: "abc123",roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]})
```

it returns `Successfully added user`. Then I reconfigure the `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
storage:
   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
   journal:
     enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Save and restarted the mongod server : `sudo service mongod restart`

try to connect with: `mongo -u "adminUser" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

which is successfull, then if I change to another database with command `use testDatabase`, I cant make any operation to it.

```
use testDatabase
db.createCollection("people")
```

results:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on testDatabase to execute command { create: \"people\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

Here is registered users in my database

```
use admin
db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.adminUser", 
  "user" : "adminUser", 
  "db" : "admin", 
  "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {....} }, 
  "roles" : [ { "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" } ]
}
```

It seems that `userAdminAnyDatabase` role doesn't work anymore or is there anything wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built in roles `UserAdmin` & `UserAdminAnyDatabase` role  allows you to create  user and roles in database.

For read/ readWrite operations on database you have to create user with `read`/ `readWrite` role for that database.

Other option will be to add the role to the current user you have.

Something like this for example.

```
use test
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myTester",
    pwd: "xyz123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
             { role: "read", db: "reporting" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: It works, but Does it mean that I need to create different user for different database?

Comment: It depends on use case. You can have it either way. More here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/